# Does PostgreSQL have an equivalent to SAS' obsnum?

Tags: postgresql, sas

When converting scripts, tables, datasets, etc. from a SAS environment to a PostgreSQL environment, is there an equivalent to referencing SAS' obsnum in PostgreSQL? For example, if a query says:

```
SELECT FROM schema.table
WHERE obsnum = 1
```

Is there a way to track the observation number or similar in PostgreSQL? Or should a different approach be taken?

Thanks.

Should probably specify that I was told obsnum is a built-in SAS value associated with datasets and tables, and in my SAS scripts there is no declaration for obsnum, only a singular reference to it in a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

OBSNUM isn't an automatic variable in SAS so its a variable value. 
You should be able to use a similar query in Postgres to limit where the variable value is 1.

To add on - PROC SQL doesn't have an automatic variable to do numbering, it can use monotonic() for row numbers but it's not supported.

(wrong answer):

Try `CTID`

See your previous question, the first answer and the comments/questions.

[What exactly is the/this data statement in SAS doing? PostgreSQL equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166638/what-exactly-is-the-this-data-statement-in-sas-doing-postgresql-equivalent)

PostgresSQL 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-system-columns.html

Comment: CTID isn't exactly a number though as far as I can tell; rather, it's an ordered pair. Which of the two numbers in ctid is the one I'm looking for as a comparison?

Comment: Well then what about limit or top?

Comment: Limit and top don't seem to do what the query is looking for. The query has the clause `WHERE obsnum = 1`. Limit and top only return the number of specified records, and I believe the query is looking for multiple records with an obsnum of 1.

Comment: @Reeza: it is actually the second answer to that previous question that mentions ctid. and B J : there is no `order` in an SQL table. A table is a *set of records*

Comment: @joop It shows up first for me, depends on sort order set in your SO view I assume.

Answer (score 0):

```
        -- make(fake) a dataset
CREATE TABLE dataset
        ( val double precision NOT NULL
        );
        -- populate it with random
INSERT INTO dataset(val)
SELECT random()
FROM generate_series(1,100)
        ;

    -- Use row_number() to enumerate the unordered tuples
    -- note the subquery. It is needed because otherwise
    -- you cannot refer to row_number
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT val
        , row_number() OVER() AS obsnum
        FROM dataset
        ) qq -- subquery MUST have an alias
WHERE qq.obsnum = 1
        ;

        -- you can just as well order over ctid (the result is the same)
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT val
        , row_number() OVER(ORDER BY ctid) AS obsnum
        FROM dataset
        ) qq -- subquery MUST have an alias
WHERE qq.obsnum = 1
        ;

        -- In stead of a subquery you could use
        -- a CTE to wrap the enumeration part
WITH zzz AS (
        SELECT val
        , row_number() OVER(ORDER BY ctid) AS obsnum
        FROM dataset
        )
SELECT * FROM zzz
WHERE obsnum = 1
        ;

        -- Or, if you just want one observation: use LIMIT
        -- (order of records is not defined,
        -- but the order of ctid is not stable either)
SELECT * FROM dataset
LIMIT 1 
        ;
```